# elastic beanstalk can not find Dockerfile

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When using eb CLI

```
eb init
eb create
```

i get an error:

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-003165df12360a5c4] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment.
```

It seems like the ZIP file sent to the S3 indeed only contains README.md file. but the local folder does contain the Dockerfile and

```
eb local run
```

seems to work fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Answer**: It's because the Dockerfile wasn't committed. (By default the EB CLI deploys the [latest commit in the current branch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html#eb3-cli-git.deploy)).

I had the same problem, and figured out the reason after reading your question and answer. You probable had a new git repo with only a readme file. Once you deleted the .git directory, the EB CLI no longer treated your directory as a git repo.

Comment: You would think they would include this information in their documentation... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be solved.
After removing ".git" folder "eb create" worked.
Seems like a bug in elastic beanstalk as i don't see why the existents of a  subfolder should prevent eb from zipping the files in the directory...